# Issues with sampling distribution over bootstrapped monte carlo simulations

Tags: bootstrap, monte-carlo, central-limit-theorem

[Facebook posed an interview question](https://vimeo.com/385283671/ec3432147b) (see ~49 min mark), how many days would it take (in days) to sample every user from a population of 1000, given that you sample 10 users/day each day? Analytically, they demonstrated that the expectation is ~100 days.

For kicks, I was interested in the variance around the distribution and decided to do Monte Carlo simulations. However, the mean of my simulations was ~750 which is considerably higher than 100. I'm curious where my logic went wrong.

```py
import random

class Exp():
  def __init__(self):
    self.all = set([i for i in range(1,1001)])
    self.pool = set([i for i in range(1,1001)])
    self.itrs = 0
    while self.pool:
      self.choose()
      self.itrs += 1
  
  def choose(self,k=10): 
    chosen = set(random.choices(population=list(self.all),k=k))
    self.pool = self.pool.difference(chosen)

tests = [Exp().itrs for i in range(1000)]
```

This Exp class sets up two sets, pool and all. For each iteration, 10 users are drawn from all (due to replacement) and the difference between sets, pool and chosen, is found. This difference is saved as the new pool (the users who have not been exposed to the feature yet.) The while loop only exits after every user has been sampled at least once (pool is an empty set.)

```py
means = [np.mean(random.choices(population=tests,k=30)) for i in range(1000)]
plt.hist(means)
```

[image: Dist]
So, again, I wanted to look at the variance of this distribution, so that I could answer potential follow on questions, like ~"What number of days will give me a 90% of all users having seen the feature?" Or "What's the probability that all users will have seen the feature after an arbitrary X days?" So I applied bootstrapping and central limit theorem therein.

This just adds context; at the moment, I'm more concerned why the simulation means are magnitudes higher than the analytic expectation (~100.)

Any thoughts as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: The cited 100 days is the expected time _for a given user_ to be selected, which is a different question than the one you're answering. To me it makes sense that the expected time for every user to be selected would be much higher than this.

Comment: Check `coupon collector's problem` if the sampling scheme is to sample ten people without replacement every day, assuming they are returned to the entire population after sampling. (The wording of the initial question is unclear.)